# Get values of an array by function

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have this array

```
var user = {
    "tester": {
        id: "1",
        name: "tester"
    }
};
```

and this function

```
function get(a, b) {
return user[a].b
}
get('tester', 'id')
```

How should I fix it so that the result can be 1? Thank for your helps

Comment: FYI: 'user' is not an array, it's an object. Arrays use square brackets and numeric keys.

Comment: `var testerId = user.tester.id`

Comment: Thank you Zach for pointing that out. As you can see, I'm not a pro.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function get(a, b) {
    return user[a][b];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function get(a, b) {
    return user[a][b];
}
get('tester', 'id');
```